# Complex SQL selection query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, if-statement

I have a stored procedure which needs a different if condition to work properly.

The procedure has 2 parameter namely, @CategoryID and @ClassID, which basically come from a UI tree view functionality. @CategoryID corresponds to the parent nodes, while @ClassID corresponds to the child nodes.

Based upon the above parameters I need to make a selection(Column Code) from a table which has CategoryID and ClassID as columns.

Now there are 2 scenarios:

Scenario 1

@CategoryID:A

@ClassID:B (which is a child node of CategoryID A)

Result needed: Codes corresponding to only ClassID B, which is basically the intersection

Scenario 2

@CategoryID:A

@ClassID: C (which is not a child node for CategoryID A)

Result needed: Codes corresponding to the CategoryID A, as well as ClassID B, basically a union

The procedure which I wrote gives me correct answer for the second scenario, but the first scenario it fails. Below is my procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[uspGetCodes]
@CategoryID varchar(50),
@ClassID varchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
BEGIN TRY
DECLARE @SQLQuery NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @SQLQuery=N'SELECT Code FROM dbo.ClassToCategoryMapping WHERE '
IF (@CategoryID IS NULL OR @CategoryID='')
    BEGIN
    SET @SQLQuery=@SQLQuery + 'ClassId IN ('+@ClassID+')'
    PRINT(@SQLQuery)
    EXEC(@SQLQuery)
    END

ELSE IF (@ClassID IS NULL OR @ClassID='')
    BEGIN
    SET @SQLQuery=@SQLQuery+'CategoryID IN ('+@CategoryID+')'
    PRINT(@SQLQuery)
    EXEC(@SQLQuery)
    END

ELSE 
    BEGIN
    SET @SQLQuery=@SQLQuery+'(CategoryID IN ('+@CategoryID+') OR ClassId IN ('+@ClassID+') )'
    PRINT(@SQLQuery)
    EXEC(@SQLQuery)
    END
END TRY

BEGIN CATCH
SELECT ERROR_NUMBER() AS 'ErrorNumber', ERROR_MESSAGE() AS 'ErrorMessage', ERROR_SEVERITY() AS 'ErrorSeverity', ERROR_STATE() AS 'ErrorState', ERROR_LINE() AS 'ErrorLine'
RETURN ERROR_NUMBER()
END CATCH

END
```

The Last Else part actually does an 'OR', which gives me the union of the Codes for CategoryID's and ClassID's irrespective whether the given ClassID is a child of the given CategoryID or not.

My question over here would be, how to write the condition to achieve both the scenarios.

**Latest Sample Data:**

Scenario 1

@CategoryId=2,5, @ClassID=10 (Here 10 is the child while 2 is the parent, CategoryID 2 corresponds to ClassID's 10, 11, 12)

Expected Result:  10, 26, 27 (26 and 27 correspond to the CategoryID 5)

Scenario 2

@CategoryID=2, @ClassID=13,15 (13 and 15 is the child of a different parent, CategoryID 2 corresponds to ClassID's 10, 11 ,12)

Expected Result: 10, 11, 12, 13, 15

**Data in Table dbo.ClasstoCategoryMapping will be somewhat as below:**

```
CategoryID  ClassID  Code
2           10       200
2           11       201
2           12       202
5           26       501
5           27       502
6           15       601
6           16       602
6           17       603
7           20       701
7           21       702
7           22       703
```

I guess I have made my question quite clear, if no then, folks can ask me to edit it. I would be happy to do so. I urge the experts to assist me in this problem. Any pointers too will be quite appreciated.

Regards

Anurag

Comment: Why are you using dynamic SQL? What's wrong with `WHERE ( @CategoryID IS NULL AND ... ) OR ( @CategoryID IS NOT NULL AND @ClassID IS NULL AND ... )` etc.

Comment: Could you perhaps add an example of the data. And also the results you are expecting in the different scenarios. I think that would make it clearer what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Hi Sean, Have edited the question to add sample data..Please have a look

Comment: Hi ta.speot.is, the question over here is not of dynamic and static quesries, once the procedure is correct I would for sure change the dynamic queries. Thank you

Comment: [Table Valued Parameters](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489.aspx)

Comment: Any sample code Mr. Michael, where table valued parameters have been used in the above context or somewhat similar context?

Comment: I'm not sure about anyone else, but the request isn't clear. Show us a sample of what is in `dbo.ClassToCategoryMapping` in one table. In addition, show us the types of calls to the procedure you want to make. I.e., you hinted at trying to pass a comma-separated value list. That completely changes the solution. Lastly, which version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: Can you add a table of the data set you're operating with and not just what the expected results are?

Comment: Hi Michael/Thomas..added the table dbo.ClassToCategoryMapping...Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, what you require in your result set is:

(all supplied classid) + (all classid for supplied categoryid with no matching supplied classid)

That would translate to the following:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[uspGetCodes]
(
    @CategoryID varchar(50),
    @ClassID varchar(50)
)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT  COALESCE(CM.CategoryID, CM2.CategoryID) AS CategoryID, 
            COALESCE(CM.ClassID, CM2.ClassID) AS ClassID, 
            COALESCE(CM.Code, CM2.Code) AS Code
    --Matched classIDs: 
    FROM    dbo.udfSplitCommaSeparatedIntList(@ClassID) CLAS
    JOIN    dbo.ClassToCategoryMapping CM
            ON  CM.ClassId = CLAS.Value
    --Unmatched CategoryIDs:
    FULL
    OUTER
    JOIN    dbo.udfSplitCommaSeparatedIntList(@CategoryID) CAT
            ON  CM.CategoryID = CAT.Value
    LEFT
    JOIN    dbo.ClassToCategoryMapping CM2
            ON  CM.CategoryID IS NULL
            AND CM2.CategoryID = CAT.Value
END
```

I have included Category, Class and Code in the result since its easier to see what's going on, however I guess you only really need code

This makes use of the following function to split the supplied comma separated strings:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udfSplitCommaSeparatedIntList]
(
    @Values varchar(50)
)
RETURNS @Result TABLE
(
    Value int
)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @LengthValues int
    SELECT @LengthValues = COALESCE(LEN(@Values), 0)

    IF (@LengthValues = 0)
        RETURN

    DECLARE @StartIndex int
    SELECT @StartIndex = 1

    DECLARE @CommaIndex int
    SELECT @CommaIndex = CHARINDEX(',', @Values, @StartIndex)
    DECLARE @Value varchar(50);

    WHILE (@CommaIndex > 0)
    BEGIN
        SELECT @Value = SUBSTRING(@Values, @StartIndex, @CommaIndex - @StartIndex)
        INSERT @Result VALUES (@Value)

        SELECT @StartIndex = @CommaIndex + 1
        SELECT @CommaIndex = CHARINDEX(',', @Values, @StartIndex)
    END

    SELECT @Value = SUBSTRING(@Values, @StartIndex, LEN(@Values) - @StartIndex + 1)
    INSERT @Result VALUES (@Value)

    RETURN
END
```

Answer (score 1):

this is the sample query that can achieve your goal, is this what you want?

```
DECLARE @SAMPLE TABLE
(
ID INT IDENTITY(1,1),
CategoryId INT,
ClassID INT
)

INSERT INTO @sample
VALUES(2,10)
INSERT INTO @sample
VALUES(2,11)
INSERT INTO @sample
VALUES(2,12)
INSERT INTO @sample
VALUES(3,13)

DECLARE @CategoryID INT
DECLARE @ClassID Int
```

--Play around your parameter(s) here

```
SET @CategoryID = 2
SET @ClassID = 13
```

--Snenario 1

--@CategoryId=2, @ClassID=10 (Here 10 is the child while 2 is the parent, CategoryID 2 corresponds to ClassID's 10, 11, 12)

--Expected Result: 10

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM @SAMPLE WHERE CategoryId = @CategoryID AND ClassID = @ClassID)
SELECT ClassID FROM @SAMPLE WHERE CategoryId = @CategoryID AND ClassID = @ClassID
```

--Scenario 2

--@CategoryID=2, @ClassID=13 (13 is the child of a different parent, CategoryID 2 corresponds to ClassID's 10, 11 ,12)

--Expected Result: 10, 11, 12, 13

```
ELSE

SELECT ClassID FROM @SAMPLE WHERE ClassID = @ClassID OR CategoryId = @CategoryID
```

Comment: And how is this gonna help, if both the parameters are given, the result will be zero, because it won't find anything to execute..Any more ideas Mr. Chee?

Comment: just play around with the if else statement, dont remove the else statement, haha

Comment: do your have time to try it? or u just need the completed query?

Comment: I have all the time in the world..i will look at your solution..thanks Mr. Chee

Comment: your help works fine Mr. Chee, I am having some problems while passing multiple comma separated values, will work on them. Your suggestions are working pretty fine...thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select * from yourtable 
where CategoryId = @CategoryID and ClassID = @ClassID
union
select * from 
(
    select * from yourtable where ClassID = @ClassID 
    union
    select * from yourtable where CategoryId = @CategoryID
) v
where not exists (select * from yourtable where CategoryId = @CategoryID and ClassID = @ClassID)
```

Comment: hi podiluska, when there are more different group pair in database, i think ur query is not work, because basically u just select everything if there are no key pair value returned

Comment: @CheemunLow No, I select everything that matches either the class or the category, like the question states.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE FOR DELIMITED STRING**

If you have a comma delimited string then it is best to use a CLR function to create the table, but you could use a SQL function.  Examples of how to do this are easy to find with a Google search... but for reference here is one good article on the subject -> http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings  I expect at some point there will be native support on most platforms.

Given that you have a function that returns a table of one column (named ID) of type int, or an empty table on a null input. Note: You may have to have the null return a table with one row containing an invalid value (a value that will never join), say -1.

The code is as simple as this:

```
SELECT Code
FROM ClassToCategoryMapping
LEFT JOIN MakeTableFromCVS(@CategoryID) AS CatTable 
       ON CatTable.ID = CategoryID
LEFT JOIN MakeTableFromCVS(@ClassID) AS ClassTable 
       ON ClassTable.ID = ClassID
WHERE 
   CASE 
     WHEN @CatgoryID IS NULL THEN -1 ELSE CatTable.ID 
   END = ISNULL(CatTable.ID,-1) 
AND
   CASE
     WHEN @ClassID IS NULL THEN -1 ELSE ClassTable.ID
   END = ISNULL(ClassTable.ID,-1) 
AND
   COALESCE(CatTable.ID,ClassTable.ID,-1) != -1
```

The logic is the same as below.  Because the join will vary the values if it is not null we have to use a different trick.  Here we use a marker value (in this case -1) to signal the null value.  Any value that won't appear in the comma separated list will work as this marker value, remember it must be of the same type.

---

You don't need dynamic SQL here and you will find SQL server is better at optimizing if you don't use dynamic SQL.  In fact, you don't even need an if statement  If you can be sure the input is always null you can do this:

```
SELECT Code
FROM ClassToCategoryMapping
WHERE
```

**How this works**

This query checks for both CategoryID and ClassID columns match the incoming parameters but "ignores" the input when they are null by checking the column against itself.  This is an handy SQL trick.

Note if you do need to check for empty strings then this will be almost as fast

```
DECLARE @myCatID varchar(max)
DECLARE @myClassID varchar(max)

SET @myCatID = @CategoryID
SET @myClassID = @ClassID

IF LTRIM(RTRIM(@CategoryID) = '' THEN SET @myCatID = NULL
IF LTRIM(RTRIM(@ClassID) = '' THEN SET @myClassID = NULL

SELECT Code
FROM ClassToCategoryMapping
WHERE CatgoryID = ISNULL(@myCatID,CategoryID) 
  AND ClassID = ISNULL(@myClassID,ClassID)
```

You can replace `ISNULL()` with `COALESCE()` if you want... they do the same thing in this case.

Comment: Hi Mr.Hogan..could you please go through the originL question once again..I have edited the question to include the latest sample data which has comma separated values..Thank you